# python Writing to a file

Tags: python

I am trying to do my first assignment about Writing to a file in python. Can any one help me why I am getting an output of the following type? Thank you!
Contents of file log.txt:

Contents of file log.txt should be:

Attencion, attencion. 10, 10, 22, 33, Adios.

**My Code is:**

```
fileName=input("Give a file name:: ")
filetext=input("Write something: ")
readfile = open("fileName","w")

readfile.write( filetext )

print("Wrote",filetext," to the file",fileName)

readfile.close()
```

**Assignment:**
Unsurprisingly, the second exercise in this chapter discusses the task of writing to a file. Create a program which prompts the user for a file name "Give a file name: " and then for an input "Write something: ". After this, the program writes the string given by the user to the file and reports "Wrote [input] to the file [name].". When working correctly, the program prints something like this:

> > > 

Give a file name: log.txt

Write something: Attencion, attencion. 10, 10, 22, 33, Adios.

Wrote Attencion, attencion. 10, 10, 22, 33, Adios. to the file log.txt.

> > > 

Example output

Give a file name:: log.txt
Write something: Attencion, attencion. 10, 10, 22, 33, Adios.
Wrote Attencion, attencion. 10, 10, 22, 33, Adios.  to the file log.txt

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The output of the program or the file not being written?

Comment: Explain yourself a little bit better, I really didn't understand which is the problem

Comment: Hi, when I compile the code, the output on the screen looks exactly the same but at the end it says this: Contents of file log.txt:

Contents of file log.txt should be: 

Attencion, attencion. 10, 10, 22, 33, Adios.                                                               I guess the content of log.txt is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you use the string `"fileName"`, instead of the variable name `fileName`:

```
readfile = open("fileName","w")
```

This will create a new file called `fileName`, *not* use the name the user supplies (e.g. `log.txt`). Instead, use:

```
readfile = open(fileName, "w") # remove quote marks
```